# Angular two way data-binding in dependent fields

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I needed help. 1st of sry for my english.
Im trying to create 3 fields that dependent from each other, for exp:

```
$scope.model = {
    a: 12,    // a = c - b
    b: 14,    // b = c - a
    c: null   // c = a + b
};

<input ng-model="model.a">
<input ng-model="model.b">
<input ng-model="model.c">
```

I'd like to calculate value of each field when one of them will be changed

**UPDATE 1:**
Sry I forgot important part of the problem. How to create abstract model for dynamically variables and dependencies? We can change variables from controllers, so is it possible to create such thing? =/

Example (as I see this):

```
angular.module('App').controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        items: [
            {id: 'some another field'},
            {id: 'a', calculate: 'c - b'}, 
            {id: 'b', calculate: 'c - a'}, 
            {id: 'c', calculate: 'a + b'},
            {id: 'some another field'}
        ]
    }
});

angular.module('App').directive('calculate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // The magic appears here :D
        }
    }
});

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.items", ng-attr-calculate="item.calculate">{{ item.value }}</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I done it for me, here is example: https://github.com/grammka/ngTableCalculate
Maybe will be useful for smbd. It's half abstracted, so if smbd fork it and make yum it will be nice :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done it for me, here is example: https://github.com/grammka/ngTableCalculate Maybe will be useful for smbd. It's half abstracted, so if smbd fork it and make yum it will be nice :D

Answer (score 1):

just add on all your fields

```
<input ng-model="model.a" ng-change="compute()">
<input ng-model="model.b" ng-change="compute()">
<input ng-model="model.c" ng-change="compute()">
```

and in your controller define

```
$scope.compute = function() {
  //Do your calculation HERE
};
```

Comment: Yeah it's ok for this way only, sry.. my bad. I meant the big problem is if u needed to change variables from controller.. ofc we can use $watcher on every variable.. but what if we want to add variables dynamically. Im trying to understand if we could create abstract model. I will update question now

Answer (score 0):

You can have a $watch on the collection using $watchCollection function of angular to look for any changes in the scope variable model and do the calculations as necessary.

Code for $watchCollection:

```
$scope.$watchCollection("model",function(newValue, oldValue){
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    $scope.model.a = $scope.model.c - $scope.model.b;
    $scope.model.b = $scope.model.c - $scope.model.a;
    $scope.model.c = $scope.model.a + $scope.model.b;
  }
});
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j88xVSXaM70hPcyo4QxY?p=preview)

Reference for [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (search for $watchCollection in this page)

Comment: your example doesn't work coz when u trying to change field 'a' ur watcher calculate value of field 'a' as 'c - b' although for exm c == 0, b == 0.. so u need to watch each field separately

Comment: aah yes...u can have separate watchers for a, b, and c let me update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Even I am not sure how to implement for angular, one suggestion is to separate view fields from logical actual set. i.e Keep two different set of fields for view and logic calculation.

Whenever a change happen trigger a function in service and cross check the validity inside service. Based on outcome do whatever in the UI to view fields...

This way, you could suggest better way to the user in intuitive way...